# How to view email of any provider in a Web Browser different from the provider website?

Tags: web-apps, email

I have an email account with my hosting package. Is there a web service that allow me to view my emails from any web browser without selfhost on my server or use the webmail of my hosting package?

I tried mail2web.com and mymail.com but doesn't seem to work none of them. Does someone use it and works for them?

Do you know any alternatives?

Don't tell me about security, it's not this my interest.

Comment: You already mentioned the two most popular ones... so if they don't work why do you think the others will? It is probably rather that you have an issue with how to do the setup.

Comment: Maybe because the websites mentioned are discontinued, genius?

Comment: Many providers allows POP3 or IMAP access in addition to webmail.  Is your provider web-based only?  Gmail has **"check mail from other accounts"**  Did you try that?  It imports your email from a compatible account into an existing gmail account.